# How to open url in browser from UNNotificationAction response when the app is in Inactive State

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios10

I am working on ios 10 Rich media push notification in Objective-C. I want to open a url when **UNNotificationAction** button pressed. I got the click response inside the followig method :

```
     -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{
        NSDictionary * userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
        NSArray *btnArray = userInfo[@"aps"][@"btnArr"];
        NSString *urlString = [btnArray valueForKey:@"url"];    //Supose url = www.google.com
         NSURL *url = nil;
             if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [urlString hasPrefix:@"https://"]) {
                    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
                } else {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@",urlString]];     //now url = https://www.google.com
                    }

// Here the url that will be hit = https://www.google.com
          if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
            if ([[url absoluteString] isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@""] || [[url absoluteString] length] == 0) {
         NSLog(@"action url is empty");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
                    }
               }
        }
```

But it is also working only when the app is in foreground state only. I want to open url in all state of app (i.e. Inactive,Active and Background States).
Could anyone help me to achieve my goals.Kindly give any reference ode if possible,